# Bootstrap.js - how to automatically display a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I like the Bootstrap library by Twitter and I would like to try to use into it in my simple page. I need there after loading the page automatically display [the modal window](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal). Could anyone give me a tip, how is possible to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well that shouldn't be too hard... do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my-modal').modal(options)
});
```

Comment: what are available attributes to put in options?

Comment: For that, my dear @DivpreetSingh, I'd like to redirect you to [the manual](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 4):

Your modal...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formSaludo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

If ulike modal opened... Use  **style="display: block;"** and **class="modal fade in"**

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="formSaludo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
```

Answer (score 2):

This modal load when the page is ready.

```
<body>
    <div id="top"> 
       <a tabindex="-1" href="#" id="metadata-link" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">Metadata</a>
    </div>

   <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display:none;">
      <div class="modal-header">header<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a></div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
   </div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#top').find('a').trigger('click');

    });
</script>
```

Best regards.